# Azure Logic App Sql Connector

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I am working on Logic App that pulls CDC Data from SQL Server Db. I am using Get Rows operation but the problem comes in when I try to use the **Filter Query** parameter.

- `code eq '793'` (works)
- `__$operation eq '2'` (Not working)
- `@{string('__$operation')} eq '2'` (Not working)

I think the problem might be with the "$" character.

Error message

```
{  
  "status": 400,  
  "message": "Syntax error at position 12 in '__$operation eq '2'' "  
}
```

Can someone please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is a reserved character according to [OData Normative](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#RFC3986), you should percent-encoding it before the URI is formed. Unfortunately, I tried percent encoding and still get syntax error, seems it's not allowed in Filter Query.
[image]

### Solution

---

Here is the solution, in Logic App you cannot use `%` in Filter Query, so you can't use `%24` for `$`, instead you should use `_x0024_`.I can successfully get the result now:

[image]

Note there are three `_` at the beginning. You can use this pattern if you have other special characters in field/column name. For example, if the field name is `Display Name` which has a space character in between, then in Filter Query, you need to convert it to `Display_0x0020_Name`

For more details about this encoding, please refer to [Encode and Decode XML Element and Attribute Names and ID Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfaz0c52(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also tried to encode $ but it didn't work.Yes you are right, creating stored procedure will solve this problem but I am not allowed to make any changes to the Db.

Comment: @SardarAli after digging a while, I've found the solution, see my updates above

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Get Rows operation but the problem comes in when I try to use the Filter Query parameter.
>
> I think the problem might be with the "$" character.

Based on my test, if the field/column contains `$` (or  `__`) and use that field in **Filter Query**, which works fine.

[image]

But if I define the field as `__$operation` that starts with `__$`, which will cause the same issue when I use it in Filter Query. <del>So if possible, you can try to modify the column name in your SQL database.</del>

Comment: `__$operation` is the meta column of CDC table, I don't think you should modify the column name

Comment: I am not familiar with change data capture operations, thanks for pointing ``__$operation`` should not modified. Based on my test, the filed contains "$" character not the cause of the issue.